# Simultaneous and Marginal distribution Proof

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,Y)$ have density $g(x,y)$ with respect to Lebesgue messure. I know that the density of $X$ is by integrating $g$ with respect to $y$ but, in a measure theoretic sense, what is the proof of that?

In online notes, the proof goes $P(X \in A) = P( X \in A, Y \in \mathbb{R}) = \dots$ and the rest follows, but in the setting of measure theory: what is $P$ ("probability") and how does the first equality follow?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $f$ is a density of $X$ if for all measurable sets $A$ you have
$$
  P(X\in A,Y\in \Bbb R) = \int_A f(x)\mathrm dx \tag{1}
$$
Now, the probability in $(1)$ we can of course write down using the join density $g$:
$$
  P(X\in A,Y\in \Bbb R) = \int_A\int_\Bbb R g(x,y)\mathrm dy\mathrm dx = \int_A \left(\int_\Bbb R g(x,y)\mathrm dy\right)\mathrm dx
$$
so of course if you define $f(x) = \int_\Bbb R g(x,y)\mathrm dy$ you satisfy $(1)$.